# How to Install Ruby Java Bridge (RJB) on mac/ osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rjb

Does anyone know how to install RJB on mac correctly, I already use RJB gem, but .jar file still can not loaded, always return "nil". thanks

Comment: What commands are you running? More information would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Kieran, thanks for your attention, I tried to use https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp , I wish to create suggestion result for search modul on my app which I used postgree fulltext search. eg: if I put keyword "home" then the result not just record of containing of "home" but maybe containing of "house" or "housing" or something that related with residence. or is there any suggestion for to do this with another gem/ plugin or something. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed the instructions [here](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/), and make sure you set Java run time to your library path. (Sorry I'm not sure hot to do it in Mac), But having said that, I used to rjb some time back and not had a good experience. There were some memory leaks.

My personal opinion is is possible go for Jruby as it's more solid when trying to get Ruby and Java working together

Comment: yes I'm already followed that link and setup java run time and setup the library path, I think I missed something, but I dunno, oh really it really memory leacks? I thought Jruby is more worse, hmm.. thanks for your advise, btw I already explain what I wish todo with this above, so maybe you have any another advise for me. thanks